# параллельные прямые(коммутативность и ассоциативность)

Tags: prolog

Дано задание составить программу, содержащую данные факты и правила, связывающие между собой параллельные и перпендикулярные прямые. даны прямые a,b,c, соответственно прямая а параллельна прямой b, прямая b параллельна прямой c. Данных о перпендикулярности в моем случае нету. Вот код программы:

```
domains
 s=symbol
predicates  
 paraleln(s,s)
 paraleln2(s,s)
 paraleln3(s,s)
clauses
 paraleln(a,b).
 paraleln(b,c).
 paraleln2(a,b):-paraleln(a,b);paraleln(b,a).
 paraleln3(b,c):-paraleln2(b,a),paraleln2(a,c);
 paraleln2(c,a),paraleln2(a,b);paraleln2(b,c).
```

Задать вопрос:

```
*Параллельны ли указанные прямые?
*Перпендикулярны ли указанные прямые?
*Какие прямые параллельны(перпендикулярны) указанной прямой?
*Какие прямые параллельны или перпендикулярны указанной прямой?
*Существуют ли прямые, одновременно параллельны и перпендикулярны?
```

Что то делаю не так, ибо если просто делать как факт, то смысл от описанных правил нету(эти правила показаны как примеры (коммутативности и ассоциативности). И если дописать "paraleln(все варианты параллельности), то он выдает ответ и всё, но считаю не правильно это, тогда в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

> Данных о перпендикулярности в моем случае нету.

В таком случае упростим вопросы Вашего задания:

**Задать вопрос:**

**1. Параллельны ли указанные прямые?**

**2. Какие прямые параллельны указанной прямой?**

> Что то делаю не так, ибо если просто делать как факт, то смысл от описанных правил нету(эти правила показаны как примеры (коммутативности и ассоциативности). И если дописать "paraleln(все варианты параллельности), то он выдает ответ и всё, но считаю не правильно это, тогда в чем ошибка?

Данную задачу можно представить так:

```
domains
 ln = symbol % line name
 rn = symbol % rule name
 pn = symbol % fact name

predicates
fact( fn, ln, ln ).
rule( rn, ln, ln ).
q1.
q2.

clauses

fact( parallel, a, b ).
fact( parallel, b, c ).
%
rule( commutativity, A, B ):-
    fact( parallel, A, B );
    fact( parallel, B, A ).
rule( commutativity, C, A ) :-
    fact( Fact, A, B );
`   fact( Fact, B, C ).

%
rule( associativity, B, C ) :-
    ( 
       fact( parallel, B, A ),
       fact( parallel, A, C ) 
    );
    ( 
       fact( parallel, C, A ),
       fact( parallel, A, B )
    );
    fact( parallel, B, C ).

 q1 :- prompt( "Прямая 1:", L1 ), 
       prompt( "Прямая 2:", L2 ),
       write( "Параллельны ли указанные прямые?" ),
       rule( _ , L1, L2 ).

 q2 :- prompt( "Прямая :", L1 ),
       findall( L2, rule( _, L1, L2 ), Ls ),
       write("Прямые, параллельные указанной прямой", Ls).       

goal
    q1, q2.
```